# How can I get the form values on the submit event of a Redux-Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using [Redux-Form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) and I'm trying to get the form values when the user clicks submit.

[These are the outer form props](http://redux-form.com/5.2.0/#/api/reduxForm?_k=efkir9). As you can see, there are submittion functions:

- onSubmit
- onSubmitSuccess
- onSubmitFail

`onSubmitSucess` and `onSubmitFail` are never called. `onSubmit` is called but with **no arguments**.

All I want is to get the form values so I can post them to an API.

How can I do that?

**EDIT (code)**

### AutoFormInternal.js

```
class AutoFormInternal extends Component {

    render() {

        let {
            componentFactory,
            fields,
            fieldMetadata,
            layout,
            handleSubmit,
            submitting
        } = this.props;

        let model = this.props.values;
        let fieldMetadataEvaluated = metadataEvaluator.evaluate(fieldMetadata, model, '', fields);

        let groupComponent = componentFactory.buildGroupComponent({
            component: layout.component,
            layout: layout,
            fields: fieldMetadataEvaluated,
            componentFactory: componentFactory
        });

        return (
            <div className="meta-form">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    { groupComponent }
                    <ButtonToolbar>
                        <Button type="submit" bsStyle="primary" disabled={submitting}>Submit</Button>
                        <Button disabled={submitting}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ButtonToolbar>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

AutoFormInternal.propTypes = {
    fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    resetForm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    componentFactory: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    entity: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    layout: PropTypes.object
};

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'simple'
})(AutoFormInternal);
```

### AutoForm.js

```
class AutoForm extends Component {

    render() {

        let {entity, layout} = metadataProvider.getEntityAndLayout(this.props.schema, this.props.entityName, this.props.layoutName);
        let componentFactory = this.props.componentFactory;
        let fieldMetadata = metadataProvider.getFields(this.props.schema, entity, layout, f => {
            f.componentFactory = componentFactory;
        });
        let fields = metadataProvider.getReduxFormFields(fieldMetadata);
        let validate = (values) => {
            return metadataValidator.validate(fieldMetadata, values);
        }

        return <AutoFormInternal
            fields={fields}
            fieldMetadata={fieldMetadata}
            entity={entity}
            layout={layout}
            validate={validate}
            componentFactory={componentFactory}
            onSubmit={() => console.log('submit')}
            onSubmitSuccess={() => console.log('submit success')}
            onSubmitFail={() => console.log('submit fail')}
             />
    }

}

AutoForm.propTypes = {
    componentFactory: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    schema: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    entityName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    layoutName: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default AutoForm;
```

Comment: Can you paste some code? The part with `handleSubmit` specifically.

Comment: @Florent sure, hold on

Comment: @Florent Just did it. Thank you

Comment: `onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}` should work. If not, maybe you should inspect your store after interacting with the form. Your fields may not be properly bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass the onSubmit function reference to the form's handleSubmit method as a parameter: `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>`. Notice that the onSubmit function reference is not being called here, you're providing it as a "callback" for form submission.

Now when the form is submitted, it should call the onSubmit function, which should take 1 parameter, the values of the entire form as an object.

```
class AutoFormInternal extends Component {

render() {

    let {
        componentFactory,
        fields,
        fieldMetadata,
        layout,
        handleSubmit,
        submitting,
        onSubmit // <-- You need to reference this function passed from the wrapper component in order to pass it to redux-form's provided handleSubmit function
    } = this.props;

    ... *snip* ...

    return (
        <div className="meta-form">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}> // <-- Here's where we pass onSubmit to redux-form's handleSubmit
                { groupComponent }
                <ButtonToolbar>
                    <Button type="submit" bsStyle="primary" disabled={submitting}>Submit</Button>
                    <Button disabled={submitting}>Cancel</Button>
                </ButtonToolbar>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
}

AutoFormInternal.propTypes = {
    fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    resetForm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    componentFactory: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    entity: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    layout: PropTypes.object
};

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'simple'
})(AutoFormInternal);`
```

---

```
... *snip* ...

return <AutoFormInternal
        fields={fields}
        fieldMetadata={fieldMetadata}
        entity={entity}
        layout={layout}
        validate={validate}
        componentFactory={componentFactory}
        onSubmit={(formValues) => console.log(formValues)} // <-- formValues should be now be populated when the form is submitted
        onSubmitSuccess={() => console.log('submit success')}
        onSubmitFail={() => console.log('submit fail')}
         />
```